# Safari browser issue with an inline CSS code

Tags: css, safari

The following inline CSS code fails with Safari browser on Windows (ver 5.1.7) while the same CSS code works fine with Chrome and Firefox.

```
<input type="button" value="myfunc1" onclick="window.open('scirptX','createSTUFF','width=700,heig‌​ht='+(screen.height-‌​150)+',resizable=yes‌​,scrollbars=yes');" style="transform: scaleX(0.8) scaleY(0.8);">
```

Comment: And Chrome and Firefox are the most recent versions?

Comment: Yes. Are you suggesting that recent versions of Safari won't have this issue?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this version of Safari is over 4 years old.